# List of different types in database section Turbo Prolog

Tags: syntax, prolog

Turbo Prolog is not as easy as it seems. Have another problem. Using Turbo Prolog 2.0.

I have two section domains and database:

```
domains

    tablet_name = symbol

database

    additional(tablet_name, [])
```

How to tell prolog to know that instead of [] will be a list of different types, like `integer, integer, symbol, integer,symbol, symbol and so on`.

If it was only integer, it would be easy, smth like `additional(tablet_name, integer*)`. But actually, i need to keep a list of different amount of data.

The result should be something like: `additional('Acer 525', [23, yes]), additional('Acer 525', [23])`

Comment: Turbo Prolog is a logic programming language, superseded by Visual Prolog. But is not a Prolog system despite its name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry I don't have Turbo Prolog available. But from [this specification page](http://wiki.visual-prolog.com/index.php?title=Language_Reference/Domains) for Visual Prolog seems you can declare compound domains with a very Prolog-like syntax. So, try

```
domains
   ...
   tablet_attr = size(integer,integer) ; weight(integer) ; ...
   tablet_attrs = [tablet_attr*]
```